# Official UML Activity diagram meta model?

Tags: modeling, uml

Is there an official UML Activity diagram meta model in form of an ecore or xsd file out there? By official I mean published by the OMG or a other consortium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the eclipse foundation has a really great UML Model in the [MDT project](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2). It is used for a lot of tools like [Rational Software Architect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Software_Architect) by IBM or [UML Lab](http://www.uml-lab.com/) by Yatta and open source ones like [TOPCASED](http://www.topcased.org/).

You can use it flattened (all package merges already executed) as EMF/ecore generated Java source. Or you can use it as .uml (XMI with UML EMF model file).

Comment: Thanks Christian,

at this page: http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/modeling_spec_catalog.htm#UML i found this node:  "Version 2.0 does not have XSD or XML associated files due to structural problems with the UML metamodel."

What does this mean? Is the UML metamodel not compatible to the EMF metamodel?

Comment: No nothing on that page relates to EMF. It only means that even the OMG member companies were not able to hack the specification into an XMI compliant tool o_O

Comment: If you are searching for the actual uml files of org.eclipse.uml2 have a look into the uml2 SDK. You can install it into eclipse via "Install New Software..." or download it here: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=uml2
Then have a look into the eclipse projects org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources, org.eclipse.uml2.types, org.eclipse.uml2.uml.profile.l2 and org.eclipse.uml2.uml.profile.l3  (e.g. import them into your workspace).